# Find the largest possible coefficient k2 for a tight lower asymptotic bound of g(n)

Tags: algorithm

The function is

2n lg(n+2)² + ((n+2)²)lg(n/2)

I have expanded the equation and gotten the order of growth of

n²lg n

For Big O,

n²lg n <= k1(n²lg n)
where k1 = 1 and n0 = 1

For Omega,

n²lg n => k2(n²lg n)
where k2<1 and n0 = 1 for the equation to be true.
How do I find the tightest bound for k2?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What specifically are you asking? You've found a big Omega bound for g already, which is a tight bound for g. You say in the question you're looking for a "tightest bound for k2", but what does that mean? k2 looks like a constant in the definition of big Omega, which I think means you're confused, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding your words.

Comment: Glad that your bound is asymptomatic. But keep a mask on anyway.

Comment: When the question ask for asymptotic tight bound for f. We have to find the upper and lower bound. Big O is found, as k=1 and n0=1. The lower bound is Omega, which is what i'm struggling with!

Comment: By the way, what is the meaning of `nlg(n+2)^2`.

Comment: Please note in passing that about nothing of what you wrote is correct, sorry.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/